# Remote access to Message Queue over SSL in GlassFish

Tags: java, ssl, jms, keystore, glassfish-4.1

I'm trying to access a Message Queue configured in GlassFish but have been facing a lot of problems. The first one is regarding the Trust Store password on the client side. I can only make it work if I use the default password (changeit), I'm always getting

```
Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
```

if I try to use a different password. And yes, I'm pretty sure I'm using the correct password.
In fact, if I set the Trust Store with the default password and use the following property with a wrong value, it still works:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<wrong value>
```

Which leads me to conclude that it completely ignores this setting.
This is what I've so far:

```
System.setProperty("com.sun.CSIV2.ssl.standalone.client.required", "true");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "<my path>/truststore.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "<my password>");

Properties properties = new Properties();

System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
System.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3820");

InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(properties);

com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new com.sun.messaging.ConnectionFactory();

connectionFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqAddressList, "127.0.0.1:7676");
connectionFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqDefaultUsername, "<app user>");
connectionFactory.setProperty(ConnectionConfiguration.imqDefaultPassword, "<app user password>");

QueueConnection queueConnection = connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();

queueConnection.start();
```

So, my first question is: How can I use the non-default password on my Trust Store? Do I have to use some kind of encoding/hashing on the value?

My second question is regarding authentication. The standard way of getting the Connection Factory (via JNDI) and authenticate (via createQueueConnection(user, pass)) does not seem to be working, it always tries to use the guest account. Is there a way to use the standard approach on GlassFish or am I limited to use proprietary code?

**EDIT #1**

After digging a little deeper, I've detected a behavior that seems a bug.
Looking at the stacktrace, one of the first methods being invoked is initJKS() from com.sun.enterprise.security.ssl.impl.SecuritySupportImpl. With the help of javassist, I realized that the following section is being invoked:

```
if (masterPasswordHelper == null && Globals.getDefaultHabitat() != null) {
       masterPasswordHelper = Globals.getDefaultHabitat().getByType(MasterPasswordImpl.class);
}
if (masterPasswordHelper instanceof MasterPasswordImpl) {
       keyStorePass = masterPasswordHelper.getMasterPassword();
       trustStorePass = keyStorePass;
}
```

Causing the bypass of the next set of instructions:

```
if (keyStorePass == null) {
    keyStorePass = System.getProperty(KEYSTORE_PASS_PROP, DEFAULT_KEYSTORE_PASS).toCharArray();
    trustStorePass = System.getProperty(TRUSTSTORE_PASS_PROP, DEFAULT_TRUSTSTORE_PASS).toCharArray();}
```

And, as a consequence, to ignore the property javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword. Why is Globals.getDefaultHabitat() returning a non null value?